# ILogger : log method : unable to send an user defined variable

Tags: c#, logging, nlog

I am have a existing project where NLog is used. So I already have debug/warn methods written in my existing project.

Now extending the project. In the new project I want to use `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`.

Instead of writing from scratch, I am trying to use the existing code. something like:

```
   public void Log<TState>(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, LogInfo logInfo, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
    {
        NLog.ILogger logger = null; 

       if (logLevel == Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Debug)
        {
            logger.Debug(logInfo, logLevel );
        }

    }
```

The class `LogInfo` is an user defined class. I can not do like that because of the method is defined as

```
public void Log<TState>(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState logInfo, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
```

Now how can a pass the `logInfo` to the method? Any good documentation on `Tstate` will be appreciated too.

Comment: When you setup the Microsoft.Extension.Logging then just register NLog as LoggingProvider. Then NLog will capture LogEvents sent to MEL-ILogger. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/wiki/Getting-started-with-.NET-Core-2---Console-application

Answer (score 0):

As Snakefoot noted,

If you like to use the `ILogger` injection with NLog, you could use the

- the [NLog.Web.AspNetCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Web.AspNetCore) package in case of ASP.NET Core, see [ASP.NET Core with NLog tutorial](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-2), or
- the [NLog.Extensions.Logging](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Extensions.Logging) package for other .NET Core applications, e.g. a console application. See [this tutorial](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/wiki/Getting-started-with-.NET-Core-2---Console-application).

When proper set-up, you could do:

```
_logger.LogInformation("Log message with {simpleText} and {@complexObject}", myString, myObject);
```

And capture those with `${message}` and/or `${event-properties:simpleText}` / `${event-properties:complexObject}`. See [How to use structured logging](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-use-structured-logging).